# What's the simplest way of creating a Virtual Machine from a Physical Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, virtualbox, vmware

I have full access to the server, although I normally use it via SSH.

I would like to have a backup of this server because it has too many configurations and running programs, crons, etc. that I wouldn't like to have to reinstall again.

I have tried running vmware converter from my windows computer. It asks for my Ubuntu Login information, but then in the second screen it asks for VMware infrastructure which I don't have nor know what it is.

I normally use VirtualBox for my virtual machines, not vmware. But I'm open to solutions.

I would also be happy with an ISO (or similar) image from my ubuntu server too. Whatever is easier to restore would be great.

Comment: Hi Stephen, so in essence, what you want to backup is the installed apps, modified settings and scripts you have on your system (Correct me if I am wrong).  Depending on your answer it could go from doing a simple backup of several folders to creating a LXC and more.

Comment: Hola Luis, yes, that's right. I'm not sure what directories should I backup, maybe using rsync ,etc. Besides I would have to backup to my windows computer, which I don't know if possible to rsync files from linux to there. But anyway, I also thought it would be nice to have a virtual machine from my physical server in order to try new things and or restore the system if it ever explodes, or something awful happens.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, my advice would be to clone the drive on a regular schedule, not use virtualisation. Though I have never tested it, you can apparently do what you are asking with VM Ware :
I see you have had issues with that, I had a quick look at the manual and it's not very helpful. There are [VM Ware forums](https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/vcenter/converter/content?filterID=contentstatus%5Bpublished%5D~objecttype~objecttype%5Bthread%5D) where you may get a lead on the actual message it's giving you.

I believe you can also create a VM from [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/uk/products/desktop/), but you would have to load it up on a MAC host.